# How to get rid of "Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties" message?

Tags: log4j, apache-spark

I am trying to suppress the message

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

when i run my Spark app. I've redirected the INFO messages successfully, however this message keeps on showing up. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add your spark's conf folder to CLASSPATH variable.

Comment: @kaushal you're correct, I had to do something similar but not exactly, what you suggested here, but I am sure If i did what you suggested, this message would have gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, So I've figured out a way to do this. So basically, I had my own log4j.xml initially, that was being used, and hence we were seeing this property. Once I had my own "log4j.properties" file, this message went away.

Comment: This is the exact solution if you're using Intellij. Great job. The other answers did not work for me.

Comment: Can you please give me some details how did you get off the Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties  .I m using spark 1.6 ,running the job on yarn cluser . Unable to figure out how to pass log4j in distributed envir. I have my own log4j propertie file

Comment: Think independent of local/distributed a log4j.properties need to exist in the classpath + you need to define a root logger there, like `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console`. See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.scala for reference!

Answer (score 15):

Even simpler you just `cd SPARK_HOME/conf` then `mv log4j.properties.template log4j.properties` then open `log4j.properties` and change all `INFO` to `ERROR`. Here `SPARK_HOME` is the root directory of your spark installation.

Some may be using `hdfs` as their Spark storage backend and will find the logging messages are actually generated by `hdfs`. To alter this, go to the `HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties` file. Simply change `hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console` to `hadoop.root.logger=ERROR,console`. Once again `HADOOP_HOME` is the root of your hadoop installation for me this was `/usr/local/hadoop`.

Comment: I had to apply those changes and copy `log4j.properties` to `src/main/resources` folder for the changes to get picked up.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if your restarted the spark master if this would not be necessary?

Comment: Dunno, but I probably did restart SBT in which Spark was running.

Answer (score 7):

If you put a `log4j.properties` file under both the `main/resources` and the `test/resources` this also occurs. In this case, deleting the file from the `test/resources` and using only the file from the `main/resources` fixes the issue.

Comment: You can just copy the contents of this file to your `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` file.
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spark-3.4 just rename your `log4j.properties` to `log4j2.properties` to make use of your logging configurations. Any changes I made to log4j.properties had no effect on logging.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers above did work for me using SBT. Turns out you need to **explicitly** define an appender in your `log4j.properties`, such as:

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN, stdout
log4j.logger.com.yourcompany=INFO, stdout
```

Put this in your `resources` directory and Bob's your uncle!